# Variable number of fields in Google Form?

Tags: google-forms

Is there a simple way to make a Google Form have a variable number of a fields based on numerical input from a previous field (e.g. asking how many people will be registered and then providing that number of name fields)?

I've tried Googling and looking on Stack Overflow, but couldn't find anything. I'm not really familiar with JavaScript, although I know a small amount of PHP.

Thanks!